# Adding Text to figure without distorting the shape/shadow. CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

I've been trying to add text to the inside of these spheres. In google chrome, the shadow underneath is set to appear on hover. I am unsure if it works for other browsers, but the stage area for the shadow means I am having trouble adding text.

```
Text A, Text B, Text c, Text D
```

Are appropriate names.

If anyone can help, that would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/fnjw92dt/

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a paragraph inside the actual figure like so:

```
<div class="stage">
        <figure class="blueball" onclick="$('.main').moveTo(3);"><p>something here</p><span  class="shadow"></span></figure>    
</div>
```

Then you can style it however you want:

```
figure{position:relative;}
figure p{position:absolute; top:60px; left:40px;}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/fnjw92dt/3/)